# Pass dynamic parameters to a custom ad tag on Doubleclick

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I have an ad tag that comes from an ad network and has the following structure

```
<div class="ad_container"> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    api_key = X;
    param1 = Y;
    param2 = Z;
    ...
  </script>
  <script src="path_to_ad_network_js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <div class="no_content" style="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

The tag has to be placed on a number of dynamically generated pages with `param1` and `param2` set dynamically based on the content of the generated page (e.g., it can be a latitude and longitude which I do not know in advance.
I am new to Doubleclick, but as far as I understand, I have to create an Ad Unit with Custom Creative that contains that ad tag and then include a corresponding Doubleclick tag into the template that generates the web page.

However I cannot figure out how to pass values of `param1` and `param2` to the ad network, since now Doubleclick is sitting in the middle and I don't have access to the original ad tag anymore.

Is it possible. If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Free-form key-values custom target and then access it from your custom ad code using the macro %%PATTERN:key%%

You could find more info about the targeting tags in https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/112648?hl=en
and about macros in https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/2376981?hl=en